# Do anonymous listeners increase heap size?

Tags: java, android, listener

I was wondering if it is a good practice to use anonymous listeners?

For example I have a list of 50 items. Each of them has a `onClickListener` which is implemented using anonymous listener. Does that mean that I create 50 new items in to heap?

```
for (x;x;x) {
   item.setOnClickListener(new OnClikListener() {
      ...
    });
}
```

And if I just create 1 listener object and then assign those 50 list items to that single listener. Will it be more efficient?

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
   ...
};

for (x;x;x) {
   item.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: See also [Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/performance.html#object_creation) from Android performance guidelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that it's anonymous is irrelevant. Every object instance you create goes on the heap. If you can reuse the same listener for many buttons, then definitely do it: it will need less memory, and will generate less garbage.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a simple rule: every time you execute a `new` a new object is created. It doesn't matter that the class you instantiate is an anonymous one.

If the objects created are all the same (i.e. you don't close over some changing variable) then replacing them with a single shared instance is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it takes time. In fact you not only are creating the listeners as objects but as classes (but those come already compiled).

2) Yes it will be more efficient. That said, unless your listener needs lots of resources it will not improve performance much. Decide if added code complexity is worth it.